# VSCode not finding unit tests

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code

For some reason my VSCode is not finding my unit tests in my "Test Explorer".  It is able to find the class but not any of the methods in the class.  I think that I must have something misconfigured in my vscode setup but not sure what.

Below is my stub of a class that I am trying to run.

```
/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest 
    extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Create the test case
     *
     * @param testName name of the test case
     */
    public AppTest( String testName )
    {
        super( testName );
    }

    /**
     * @return the suite of tests being tested
     */
    public static Test suite()
    {
        return new TestSuite( AppTest.class );
    }

    /**
     * Rigourous Test :-)
     */
    public void testApp()
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you're programming in Java, I would strongly encourage you to try Eclipse (my preference) or IntelliJ or NetBeans.

Comment: Yeah, i want to minimize the amount of time in java too.   I mostly write in GO but I need to put together a microservice in java.  Was hoping to use the same tools but proving to be more challenging that I expected.  Running tests seems pretty basic of an IDE though.  Might go down the eclipse route.

Comment: VSCode is hands-down my choice for stuff like Angular and dotNet Core on Linux; Eclipse for Java (including Java/Spring Boot web services).  SUGGESTION: maybe something like the Eclipse GoLang plugin might give you an "everywhere IDE": https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/golang

Comment: Yeah, I setup eclipse for Java and it worked fine.  No way I will give up VSCode for my other development.  Having used eclipse for years, I really have appreciated the switch to VScode.   Golang, K8s, Docker, and GRPC integration is super slick on VSCode.    I won't be doing java that much so having two ide's isn't the end of the world.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: I love VSCode, too.  One Q: what the heck is the deal with the default "black background?"  I thought white text on black died when Steve Jobs introduced the Mac and people stopped buying VT100 terminals?

Answer (score 10):

1.make sure you have installed J**ava Test Runner** extension

2.open the `.classpath` file and change

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" />
```

to

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="build/classes/test">
   <attributes>
      <attribute name="test" value="true" />
   </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

more infomation about [Unit Test](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing)

Comment: upvote... can you please point out where exactly this config change is mentioned?

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem. All my test classes were not annotated with "Run Test" and "Debug test".
I fixed the problem in vs code the following way:

In my Java Projects overview within the vs code ( In the Explorer section with open editors etc.) click on the "more actions" button ( the three dots ).

[image]

Click : "Clean workspace"

Accept the prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, somehow I created the test class under the normal java folder (main/java), and not under the test folder(main/test). Moving this test class under test folder fixed the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use JUnit 4's annotation:

**AppTest.java**

```java
public class AppTest {
    @Test
    public void testApp() {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

**SuiteClass.java**

```java
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({AppTest.class})
public class SuiteClass {

}
```